# Efficiently delete multiple records

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql, executemany

I am trying to execute a delete statement that checks if the table has any SKU that exists in the SKU column of the dataframe. And if it does, it deletes the row. As I am using a for statement to iterate through the rows and check, it takes a long time to run the program for 6000 rows of data.

I used executemany() as it was faster than using a for loop for the delete statement, but I am finding it hard to find an alternative for checking values in the dataframe.

```
sname = input("Enter name: ")
cursor = mydb.cursor(prepared=True)
column = df["SKU"]
data=list([(sname, x) for x in column])
query="""DELETE FROM price_calculations1 WHERE Name=%s AND SKU=%s"""
cursor.executemany(query,data)
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Is there a more efficient code for achieving the same?

Answer (score 0):

You could first use a `GET id FROM price_calculations1 WHERE Name=%s AND SKU=%s`
and then use a MYSQL `WHILE` loop to delete these ids without the need of a cursor, which seems to be more performant.

See: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6148/sql-server-loop-through-table-rows-without-cursor/

---

A `WHILE` loop without the previous get, might also work.

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/while.html

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping, try to do all the work in a single call to the database (this guideline is often applicable when working with databases).

Given a list of name / sku pairs:

```
pairs = [(name1, sku1), (name2, sku2), ...]
```

create a query that identifies all the matching records and deletes them

```
base_query = """DELETE FROM t1.price_calculations1 t1
                 WHERE t1.id IN (
                SELECT t2.id FROM price_calculations1 t2
                 WHERE {})
             """
# Build the WHERE clause criteria
criteria = "OR ".join(["(name = %s AND sku = %s)"] * len(pairs))
# Create the query
query = base_query.format(criteria)
# "Flatten" the value pairs
values = [i for j in pairs for i in j]

cursor.execute(query, values)
cursor.commit()
```

Comment: When deleting critical data, make sure you have a backup in the delete removes more records than expected.